# Install Analytics for Google Worskapce Marketplace Add-On

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Drive Add-On published on the Google Workspace Marketplace. Under APIs and Services > Google Workspace Marketplace SDK > Analytics, I'm able to see the installation analytics for one month. I'm not able to fetch any install analytics beyond a month. I want to see historical data to understand trends. Can someone help how to obtain it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/use-analytics

Comment: @JohnHanley yeah i saw this page, the problem is that the graphs which i get are only showing data of one month, i want to see historical data.